# Getting an event when angular navigate to a module or away from it

Tags: angular, module, routes

Suppose I have a DevicesModule and the route is defined as usual:

```
{ path: 'devices',  loadChildren: () => import('./pages/devices/devices.module').then(mod => mod.DevicesModule) }
```

I want to receive events when navigating to '/devices' or away from it, the reason is that the module provides a service which holds a data that I want to clean from memory when navigating away from the page.
In fact, navigating away from the module is more important then navigating to it.

I have a few ideas but each of them involve building an entire mechanism.
I searched and could not find a clear and simple way to do it, something that is builtin in angular.

some of the ideas I had:
1. use guards on the route - canActivate and canDeactivate.

```
{ path: 'devices',  loadChildren: () => import('./pages/devices/devices.module').then(mod => mod.DevicesModule), canActivate: [ToModuleGuard], canDeactivate: [FromModuleGuard] }
```

I can get the class name and the reference to the instance of DevicesModule, but only when calling
   a private variable in the routeConfig.
It's kind of a hack and is is not desired.
2. get the route path in the constructor of DevicesModule and use it in the guards.

```
    router.events
     .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
     .subscribe(routerData => {
        someService.addPath(routerData.url, this);
    });
```

I haven't checked if it works with sub routes, and how it works with route parameters.
3. override the 'then' function in the route path:

```
      const a = import('./pages/devices/devices.module').then(mod => {
        const module = mod.DevicesModule;
        someService.addPath('/devices', module);
        return module;
      });
```

this does not provide the DevicesModule instance, only the class definition.
    this approach also pose problems with sub routes.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hey there, first of all, let me see if I understood you properly. You want to know when the client navigated in and out of a specific route, especially when they navigated out, as so you can clean data left behind. You tried canDeactive and canActive, and no success. What about resolvers?

Comment: Hey @JorgePires, I think that resolvers works only upon entry to a component. however I came up with an idea, whenever I fetch items from the server in my service, I will keep the url and start an interval. on every interval I will check the url, and if it changes then I will clear the data. I haven't implemented it yet but it's suppose to work.

Comment: Since you did not reply, I did not send it to you. I saw something that may help you from the book I just read. Let me know if you are still opened to try!

Comment: Hey @JorgePires, I saw your comment here that I did not replay. however I did reply to you, please check my comment above. on any case, I will be interested to to hear about what you were reading, you are welcome to write it here and I will try it. thanks.